# Simple Ruby rack app. Load all subfolders

Tags: html, ruby, rack, assets

I am trying to create simple rack app with static pages.

The structure of my app:

```
public
 |-index.html
 |-css
   |-skins
     |-blue
       |-blue.css
     |-yellow
      |-yellow.css
     ....many more...
 |-js
   |-bootstrap
      |-aide
       |-abide.js
   ...many more...
config.ru
Gemfile
```

My config.ru file

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"
run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

The problem is that inside each folder "js", "css" I have hundreds of subdirectories and files and don't what to specify them manually. Can I load all subfoldres at once?

**EDIT**

With above configuration, when I ran `rackup` and pointed browser to `localhost:9292`. I ve just seen white screen loading. I thought that problem could be that subdirectories aren't loaded. But after I ve looked into log I found that my assets are being loaded in infinite loop and that's why app doesn't respond.

like

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2014 14:35:01] "GET /js/gmap3.min.js?_=1390559355618 HTTP/1.1" 200 29735 0.0015
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2014 14:35:01] "GET /js/waypoints.min.js?_=1390559355619 HTTP/1.1" 200 8044 0.0012
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2014 14:35:01] "GET /js/bootstrap/tab.js?_=1390559355620 HTTP/1.1" 200 3420 0.0009
```

All assets are loaded with 200 success status. I don't have any additional specific configurations. Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'mail'
gem 'rack'
```

Comment: Ilya, i'v tried on my local machine, every thing works perfect, can you show some errors outputs?

Comment: Hi CodeGroover, thanks , I ve updated my question

Comment: can you print out a corresponding log output (pastie or github gists)?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see in you logs an infinite loops.

Comment: Here is pastebin http://pastebin.com/KsC5bvHj. Loading of assets repeats again and again if I just open localhost:9292

Comment: Can you try to load in you index.html only one specific JS file and temporary comment in all others to make sure you don't repeats you self. Keep in touch.

Comment: Hi, it worked, not sure why this happens if I load other files, need to check

Comment: If I just open index.html - it works, if I start server I encounter the loop. But anyway, I think I found right direction, You can post it as answer and I l be happy to accept

Comment: I'v post an answer, acceptable? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct index.html source could be a solution.

To debug what is happening, you can try to load your index.html with only one specific JS/Css file and temporary comment in all others to make sure you don't repeats you self.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I gave up and simply used ruby on rails public folder :)